# How can I control the x position of boxplots in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

First, a quick example to set the stage:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame( 
  x=rep( c(1, 2, 4, 7), times=25 ), 
  y=rnorm(100), 
  gp=rep(1:2, each=50) 
)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(x), y=y))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(gp)))
```

[image]

I would like to produce a similar plot, except with control over the x position of each set of boxplots. My first guess was using a non-factor `x` aesthetic that controls the position along the x-axis of these box plots. However, once I try to do this it seems like `geom_boxplot` doesn't interpret the aesthetics as I would hope.

```
p + geom_boxplot( aes(x=x, y=y, fill=factor(gp)) )
```

[image]

In particular, `geom_boxplot` seems to collapse over all x values in some way when they're non-factors.

Is there a way to control the `x` position of boxplots with ggplot2? Either through specifying a distance between each level of a factor aesthetic, some more clever use of non-factor aesthetics, or otherwise?

Comment: For some reason your 2 plots are not displaying. I took a look in the editing panel but cannot see what should be changed.

Comment: I'm confused by this too -- if I copy and paste the links and open them manually, they work...

Comment: I was able to see them using the links to the SO versions of them, too. Color me puzzled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_discrete()` to set positions (ticks) for the x axis.

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(x), y=y))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(gp))) + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits=1:7)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this with the `group` aesthetic.  However, I'm not sure why you cannot just pass `x` to the `group`.  This doesn't work:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=factor(gp), group=x))
```

But this does:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=factor(gp), group=paste(x, gp)))
```