# Spacing between boxplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been working with ggplot2 a lot over the past few weeks and was wondering if anyone could help me solve this problem I am having.

When I plot my boxplot my boxes are touching each other.  I would like them to have a little bit of space between them.  Is there a way to accomplish this? I am sure there is and I am just not seeing it.[image]

Comment: could you provide data and show us your code? We'll be able to help better. Off the top of my head, I think this has something to do with `geom_bar(position = position_dodge(.))` parameter where `.` = value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085238/adding-space-between-bars-in-ggplot2?rq=1

Answer (score 26):

Let's borrow the reproducible example provided by Kevin Ushey in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528668/how-can-i-control-the-x-position-of-boxplots-in-ggplot2):

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame( 
  x=rep( c(1, 2, 3, 4), times=25 ),
  y=rnorm(100), 
  gp=rep(1:2, each=50) 
)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(x), y=y))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(gp))) #example 1
```

[image]

Then, following the advice of Arun, I tested the `(position = position_dodge(.))` but with `geom_boxplot` instead of `geom_bar`, and it worked.

In this case, it was not necessary to change the boxes width.

So, changing the last line of the above code to:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(gp)),position=position_dodge(1))
```

did the trick.

[image]