# Plotting two boxplots at one x position using R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot multiple boxplots above/below each other instead of next to each other in `R` using `ggplot2`.
Here is an example:

```r
library("ggplot2")
set.seed(1)
plot_data<-data.frame(loc=c(rep(1,200),rep(2,100)),
                      value=c(rnorm(100,3,.5),rnorm(100,1,.25),2*runif(100)),
                      class=c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100),rep("C",100)))
ggplot(plot_data,aes(x=loc,y=value,group=class)) +
       geom_boxplot(fill=c("red","green","blue"))
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: example plot]

As you can see, the blue boxplot is centered around its `loc` value (2.0), while the red and green ones have only half the width and are plotted to the left and right of their shared `loc` value (1.0).
I want to make both of them the same width as the blue one and plot them directly above each other.

How can I achieve this?

Note that I am sure that the boxplots won't overlap for the data I am going to visualize, just as they don't for the given example data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `position = "identity"`:

```r
ggplot(plot_data,aes(x=loc,y=value,group=class)) +
       geom_boxplot(fill=c("red","green","blue"),position = "identity")
```

[image]

The default for `geom_boxplot` is to use `position = "dodge"`.

Answer (score 5):

The main discussion is: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047558/spacing-between-boxplots-in-ggplot2)

Briefly, one can use `geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0))`. One can specify the distance between the boxes varying 'position_dodge' value.

Comment: While it reads less clearly as `position="identity"` (as [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17575793/2451238) by [@joran](http://stackoverflow.com/users/324364)), `position=position_dodge(0)` seems to be equivalent.