# Use geom_count in a boxplot/dotplot to indicate multiple instances of value with multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, scatter

I would like to plot the spread of my data on top of a boxplot. I've managed so far to overlap a `geom_boxplot()` with a `geom_dotplot()`. However, I have many datapoints, with many overlapping. I would like to give some indication in my plot of where most values are. I thought geom_count would be able to help out. I have however not found a way to use it with multiple groups!

Here's my first attempt at the boxplot/dotplot:

```
ggplot(data_BDI, aes(x=time, y=BDI, fill=Groups)) +
geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8))+
geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', 
             position=position_dodge(0.8),
             dotsize=0.7) + 
scale_fill_grey() + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Now I want to add the geom_count, which only gives a result per time, and not per group:

```
  ggplot(data_BDI, aes(x=time, y=BDI, fill=Groups)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', 
               position=position_dodge(0.8),
               dotsize=0.7) + 
  scale_fill_grey() + theme_classic() +
  geom_count(aes(x=time, y=BDI, group=Groups))
```

[image]

Anyway to make the different colored group-points different in size? Or any other method in displaying the overlap?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out ggbeeswarm as an alternative: https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm

There's also beanplots (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beanplot/vignettes/beanplot.pdf) and pirate plots (http://nathanieldphillips.com/2016/04/pirateplot-2-0-the-rdi-plotting-choice-of-r-pirates/) that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Never heard of any of them. I'm especially intrigued by the pirateplot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but you can use the empty circle shape so that you can overlap dots, and reduce the size of the dots if needed. Use the arguments shape and size then reduce the position dodge.

You can also increase the space between boxplots:
[Spacing between boxplots in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047558/spacing-between-boxplots-in-ggplot2)

EDIT: here is a reproducible exemple using `geom_point()` with `position_jitterdodge()` instead of `geom_dotplot()`.

```
#just creating a reproducible example:
rdu<-function(n,k) sample(1:k,n,replace=T)
time<-rdu(300,30)
data_BDI<-data.frame(BDI=time,time=rep(c("BDI","BDI.FU","BDI.FU2"),each=100),Groups=rep(rep(c("ABM","both","control","BMS"),each=25),3))
```

Solution 1 using `geom_point()`:

```
  ggplot(data_BDI, aes(x=time, y=BDI, fill=Groups)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8))+
  geom_point(aes(fill = Groups), size = 2, shape = 1, position = position_jitterdodge())+
    # geom_dotplot(binaxis='y',
    #            stackdir='center', 
    #            position=position_dodge(0.8),
    #            dotsize=0.7,
    #            shape=1) + 
  scale_fill_grey()+ 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Solution 2 using `geom_count()`:

```
ggplot(data_BDI, aes(x=time, y=BDI, fill=Groups)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8))+
  scale_fill_grey()+ 
  theme_classic()+
  geom_count(aes(fill = Groups), position = position_jitterdodge())
```

[image]

Solution 3:
If you want the dots aligned just use these parameters:

```
ggplot(data_BDI, aes(x=time, y=BDI, fill=Groups)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8))+
  scale_fill_grey()+ 
  theme_classic()+
  geom_count(aes(fill = Groups), position = position_jitterdodge(0,0,0.81))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and additional details. I've removed my review comment.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed (solution 3), Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `ggbeeswarm` solution as well. In contrast you have to calculate the `n` by yourself using the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)
data_BDI %>%
  group_by(time, Groups,BDI) %>%  # grouping to calculate the counts of duplicates
  add_count() %>% # the calculation
ggplot(aes(x=Groups, y=BDI, fill=Groups)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  # remove duplicates to keep the plot clean
  geom_beeswarm(data=. %>% distinct(), aes(size=n)) +
  facet_grid(~time) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Data

```
set.seed(1233)
rdu<-function(n,k) sample(1:k,n,replace=T)
time<-rdu(300,30)
data_BDI<-data.frame(BDI=time,time=rep(c("BDI","BDI.FU","BDI.FU2"),each=100),Groups=rep(rep(c("ABM","both","control","BMS"),each=25),3))
```