# R boxplots closer together

Tags: r, boxplot

I have made a plot with three boxplots. I would like to get the boxplots closer together, so to have less space between the values on the x-axis and btween the boxes. But I just can't figure out how. Does anyone have an idea? My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = groupA1, 
       mapping = aes(x = reorder(treatment, `mass wetness`, median, na.rm = TRUE), y = `mass wetness`)) + 
  geom_boxplot(postion = "dodge", width = 0.5, fill = "orange", position = "dodge") + theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Mass wetness (%)")
```

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(groupA1)`.

Comment: Apparently [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047558/spacing-between-boxplots-in-ggplot2) is very similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your position argument inside geom_boxplot to be:

```
position=position_dodge(x)
```

Where x is a number, for example 0.5.